# How do I clone a private key on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, clone, winscp, private-key

I have a remote server on a computer with Windows 8, using the program WinSCP to access. I want to access the server from another computer. The situation is I have not the password, so I want to know, if I can clone the private key to the another computer and how to do that. Somebody can help me?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the private key, with a key you know the passphrase too, so you can distribute it to however many machines as you want?

Comment: Private key is just a file. So copy it over to the other machine.

Comment: Martin is correct, and If you used a command line client you'd never ask such a question! As it'd be so obvious to you that the private key is a file!

Comment: thanks for your comments, somebody know where I can find the ssh files from WinSCP?

Comment: @Jeov does this help? https://cloud.google.com/compute/images/connecting/winscp_advanced_settings.png    either way  it looks like it uses ppk files so you could search your hard drive for that.  But that screen or that kind of screen should show you where it is and where to point winscp to them.. but i don't use winscp

Answer (score 0):

Private key is just a file. So copy it over to the other machine.

As you are using WinSCP and are able to login with it, you probably have a key file path configured in your stored session.

- Select your stored session on [WinSCP Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login).
- Click *Edit* button.
- Click *Advanced* button.
- Go to *[SSH > Authentication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication)* page.
- There, in the *Authentication parameters > Private key* file box, you will find a path to your SSH private key.